# How to do an image as a component template, with src as a property in Vue

Tags: html, vue.js

I am trying to make a component for images in Vue. However, in my latest attempts, the only result is that an empty  element is put in it's place.

In previous attempts, by putting a second  element inside of the outer element, I was able to get it so that there was no image tag, and all of my props were displayed as a string:

```html
<div> src=`${source}` alt=`${alternate}}` title=`${tit}}` width=`${w}}` height=`${h}}` /> </div>
```

My current code is:

```html
<body>
    <template id="comp-img-template">
        <asimage source="uclx3S.jpg" alternate="red" tit="red" w="100" h="100"></asimage>
    </template>


    <script>.
        Vue.component('asimage', {
            props: ['source', 'alternate', 'tit', 'w', 'h'],
            template: '<img src=`${source}` alt=`${alternate}}` title=`${tit}}` width=`${w}}` height=`${h}}` />'
        })
        new Vue({ el: '#comp-img-template' })
    </script>
</body>
```

I am expecting there to be an image with the modifications present in the top portion, however as mentioned before I only get the empty  tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your template string isn't valid HTML.
Something like this may work:

```
template: '< img :src="source" :alt="alternate" :title="tit" :width="w" :height="h" />'
```

Check out Vue v-bind syntax here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-bind-Shorthand

Comment: I also had to add an outer `<div>` element to the template, making the final product `template: '<div><img :src="source" :alt="alternate" :title="tit" :width="w" :height="h" /></div>'`